# Activerecord rails merging multiple select results and render rows in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Rails and doing a test for a job interview.

Almost arrived at the expected result, below you can find the code.

Example of data:

```
Bookings
id,room_id,start_date,end_date,number_of_guests
1,1,2015-06-01,2015-06-07,1
2,3,2015-06-01,2015-06-07,2
3,5,2015-06-01,2015-06-07,2
2001,6,2015-06-01,2015-06-07,2
...

Hosts
id,name,address
1,Mr Host 1,1 Camden 
2,Mr Host 2,2 Camden Street
3,Mr Host 3,3 Camden Street
4,Mr Host 4,4 Camden Street
...

Rooms
id,host_id,capacity
1,1,2
2,1,2
3,2,2
4,2,2
...
```

ActiveRecord:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :host
  has_many :bookings
end

class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
end
```

Controller:

```
  start_date = '2015-06-01' # hardcoded value for testing purposes
  end_date = '2015-06-07'   # hardcoded value for testing purposes   

  @available_rooms = Room.select(:host_id, :name, :address, :id, :number_of_guests ,:capacity)
               .joins(:bookings, :host)
               .where("bookings.number_of_guests <> rooms.capacity 
                        AND ? < rooms.capacity 
                        AND ? <= bookings.start_date
                        AND ? <= bookings.end_date", params[:guests], start_date, end_date)

  @booked_rooms = Room.select(:host_id, :name, :address, :id, :number_of_guests, :capacity)
               .joins(:bookings, :host)

  @total_rooms = Room.select(:host_id, :name, :address, :id, "0 as number_of_guests", :capacity)
               .joins(:host)

  @rooms = ((@total_rooms - @booked_rooms) + @available_rooms).sort_by(&:id)
```

View:

```
 <% if @rooms %>
<section class="rooms">
 <ul class="list-unstyled list-rooms">
  <% for room in @rooms %>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <article>
      <div class="description">
        <header>
          <h2>host#<%= "#{room.host_id}: #{room.name}" %></h2> 
          <h3><%= "#{room.address} "%></h3>
        </header>
        <p>room#<%= "#{room.id} is available (#{room.number_of_guests} booked, #{room.capacity - room.number_of_guests} free out of total #{room.capacity})" %></p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
</section>
<% end %>
```

Current Result:

```
  host#1: Mr Host 1
  1 Camden Street
  room#1 is available (1 booked, 1 free out of 2 total)

  host#1: Mr Host 1
  1 Camden Street      
  room#2 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)

  host#2: Mr Host 2
  2 Camden Street
  room#4 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)

  host#4: Mr Host 4
  4 Camden Street
  room#8 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)

  host#5: Mr Host 5
  5 Camden Street
  room#9 is available (1 booked, 1 free out of 2 total)

  host#5: Mr Host 5
  5 Camden Street
  room#10 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)
```

Expected Result:

```
  host#1: Mr Host 1
  1 Camden Street
  room#1 is available (1 booked, 1 free out of 2 total)
  room#2 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)

  host#2: Mr Host 2
  2 Camden Street
  room#4 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)

  host#4: Mr Host 4
  4 Camden Street
  room#8 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)

  host#5: Mr Host 5
  5 Camden Street
  room#9 is available (1 booked, 1 free out of 2 total)
  room#10 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)
```

I was thinking of using jquery to get the expected result but there must me a way to achieve this via active records or call some sort of a helper in the view. Thanks in advance.

Ideally, I would like to rewrite the query to retrieve results like the following row:

```
  host_id, address, total_rooms, room_id[0], booked[0], capacity[0], ... , room_id[n], booked[n], capacity[n]
```

So for the first two rows we would have:

```
  1, 1 Camden Street, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2
  2, 2 Camden Street, 1, 4, 0, 2
```

Equivalent to the frontend results:

host#1: Mr Host 1
  1 Camden Street
  room#1 is available (1 booked, 1 free out of 2 total)
  room#2 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)

host#2: Mr Host 2
  2 Camden Street
  room#4 is available (0 booked, 2 free out of 2 total)

Comment: Maybe you can write what the question is? Might give some more insight into how to answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this at the SQL level. SQL returns uniform rows, you can order them however you like, but *grouping* rows in SQL doesn't work this way. You cannot use it to return partial rows for a one-to-many relationship; it's going to return the complete joined record for each row.

If you want to output the top level record (the "host" in this case) only once, and then the associated record ("rooms") many times, you need to group your results on the front-end:

```
#...
@rooms = ((@total_rooms - @booked_rooms) + @available_rooms).sort_by(&:id)

# Produce a mapping of hosts to their rooms
@rooms_by_host = @rooms.group_by do |room|
  { id: host_id, address: room.address, name: room.name }
end
```

[`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) will group elements for which the block returns the same value. In this case, any room that has the same `host_id`, `address` and `name` will be grouped together into a nested array inside the returned hash.

And in your view, you'll now have two loops: An outer loop that iterates over the host => rooms mapping, and an inner loop for each host that loops over their rooms:

```erb
<section class="rooms">
  <ul class="list-unstyled list-rooms">
    <% @rooms_by_host.each do |host, rooms| %>
      <li class="clearfix">
        <article>
          <div class="description">
            <header>
              <h2>host#<%= host[:id] %> - <%= host[:name] %></h2> 
              <h3><%= host[:address] %></h3>
            </header>
            <ul class="rooms">
              <% rooms.each do |room %>
                <li>room#<%= room.id %> is available (<%= room.number_of_guests %> booked, <%= room.capacity - room.number_of_guests %> free out of total <%= room.capacity %>)</li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </article>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</section>
```

---

A couple of notes that you should consider if you're worried about how you're presenting yourself during an interview:

- Don't use `for x in y` in Ruby. The idiomatic way of looping is `y.each do |x|`. Using `for x in y` screams inexperience.
- `<% if @rooms %>` is a useless check, `@rooms` is an array and it cannot ever be a falsy value. You need `if @rooms.present?` or `if @rooms.any?`
- Don't use both `<%= %>` and `"#{...}"`. The inner `#{}` is completely redundant. Every place you've done this...

  ```
  <%= "#{room.address} "%>
  ```

  You should instead do this

  ```
  <%= room.address %>
  ```
- It's cleaner to let ActiveRecord build as much SQL as possible. Instead of this...

  ```
  .where("bookings.number_of_guests <> rooms.capacity 
                              AND ? < rooms.capacity 
                              AND ? <= bookings.start_date
                              AND ? <= bookings.end_date", params[:guests], start_date, end_date)
  ```

  Use this

  ```
  .where('bookings.number_of_guests <> rooms.capacity')
  .where('? < rooms.capactiy', params[:guests])
  .where('? <= bookings.start_date', start_date)
  .where('? <= bookings.end_date', end_date)
  ```

  It also keeps your parameters closer to where they're used.
- If you want to clean your views up a little, use partials. The inner-most loop could be:

  ```
      <ul class="rooms">
        <%= render rooms %>
      </ul>
  ```

  and you'd move the body of the loop to `app/views/rooms/_room.html.erb`

  ```
  <li>room#<%= room.id %> is available (<%= room.number_of_guests %> booked, <%= room.capacity - room.number_of_guests %> free out of total <%= room.capacity %>)</li>
  ```

Comment: Worked as a charm, great solution and tips on best practices.